# Deciding storage solution for an Android apps

Tags: android, android-room

I'm a bit confused on when should I use a room database instead of SharedPreferences or DataStore.

In my case I have an apps that let the user login and currently I store the logged in user data (followers, age, etc.) in a SharedPreferences, is this the correct approach for this kind of case? Should I just create a Room implementation for storing said user data? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

### First you need to understand the nature of these two things.

**Room DB** is schema so you will need to define every properties before you can use it. Such as table name, column name etc.

As it is a DB, you can easily perform a partial update on the corresponding table.

While **Shared Prefs** is just a key value pair in a xml file.

You insert `age` as key and `25` as value and that's all.

Even you can use GSON to convert the object to a JSON and store it as plain text like a non SQL DB:

key = `login-data`, value = `{"follower": "sskrts", "age": 25}`

---

### Decision

If it just a simple login session data, then I will recommend to use Shared Prefs to cache the data. It is a simpler implementation.

If you are going to store a table of data instead, both works fine, at least in my use case experience. So it will more depends on your preference of schema or non schema DB.

Note that both storage seem to have NO encryption so don't store raw credential info there.

Comment: I am "addicted" to use shared prefs to store JSON list, images to shared prefs. IMO, devices are fast enough to cater the deserialization and decoding process nowadays.

Comment: I might be wrong though, please leave a comment to me to improve my concept.

Comment: Yes it is just a simple login session data (like age, followers count, etc.).
How about the performance, will using Room makes for a better performance?
For my current implementation I do it exactly like you said, convert the response object into a string, and I wonder what if I save each data from the response (age, followers, etc.) into its own SharedPrefs entries, what do you think about this approach?